# ADC with integrated oversampling

Tags: adc, oversampling

Using a fast ADC it is possible to sample motor currents multiple times per PWM period (instead of a single synchronous measurement) and to average the results. This technique (oversampling) can help to reduce the noise of the current measurement.

**Question:**
Are there any ADCs which have this functionality (i.e. oversampling) integrated?

E.g. I would like to trigger them once at the beginning of a PWM period, which starts the first of multiple equally spaced conversions. All conversion results are summed up inside the ADC and can be obtained as a single value (sum or scaled sum) via any interface afterwards.

Comment: Are you considering *only* stand-alone ADCs? A number of microcontrollers incorporate sampling-type (SAR) ADC's that have built-in oversampling, allowing increased resolution for the result....for example a 12-bit ADC might yield 14-bit (averaged) result.

Comment: Many MCUs can generate PWM and sample with internal ADC. What research have you done before asking, so that we don't suggest things you already know?

Comment: @glen_geek No my question is a more general one. I would also be interested in appropriate microcontrollers.
However, there is following goal: Previously I already used a rapid prototyping plattform with which I was able to sample currents with an exact multiple of the PWM frequency  (e.g. 625 x f_pwm). This brougth the big advantage that oversampling and decimation lead to a complete supression of the PWM frequency component in phase currents and even in the pulse width modulated phase voltages (which were measured as well). This is want I want to achieve again now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are. You'll find these at the large ADC manufacturer's websites when you look for "oversampling". Typically, you'll want to do that if the oversampling ADC rate would be prohibitely large, making it unfeasible/expensive to do the decimation in software or an FPGA.

Also, the SAR ADC architecture has similar effects "built into" their working principles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example some STM32 ADCs can be set to oversample, but.

If you PWM a motor, the current in it will be a sawtooth, going up and down. So, the ADC reading depends on when the current is sampled. If you oversample, you will get an average. Say this finger-painted sawtooth is your motor currrent, and the red marks are the sampling points.

[image]

Top graph, if you sample several times while the PWM is ON (or OFF) then you can average that.

Bottom graph, if the duty cycle is low, and it samples both when the PWM is ON (current rising) and when it's OFF (current going down), then average of ADC readings will be bogus.

> Previously I already used a rapid prototyping plattform with which I was able to sample currents with an exact multiple of the PWM frequency (e.g. 625 x f_pwm). This brougth the big advantage that oversampling and decimation lead to a complete supression of the PWM frequency component in phase currents and even in the pulse width modulated phase voltages (which were measured as well). This is want I want to achieve again now.

This does not require oversampling, only synchronization. If you synchronize the ADC with the PWM and sample always at the same spot on the waveform, you get rid of the sawtooth. For example you can sample at the maximum current, or the minimum current, or in the middle of the current ramp which will give you the average. Which is better depends on how your PWM is setup, but the key is it should always be at the same point in the PWM cycle.

If your problem is noise and you don't get solid ADC readings, then:

- Make sure the ADC is not sampling while the FETs are switching, but either a little bit before or after, when the switching noise is no longer present.
- If you still get a lot of noise, suspect layout/decoupling problem.

Comment: In case of the currents it does not require oversampling, but in case of the phase voltages it does. As already mentioned, I want to measure their PWM-period-average as well.

Comment: Oh yes for phase voltages oversampling is a must, especially if they are distorted and you want RMS or average values

Answer (score 0):

You can start conversion through DMA, at transfer complete you calculate a mean value. Using SVPWM there is just small window for current sampling, so the available time may not be such to take multiple measurements. The technique used is a perfect timing process that uses low side current shunts to estimate phase currents, eliminating the need of direct phase current measurement.

If you need very precise current, then use a phase measurement with floating ADC. Simple low pass filter would give the exact current, without the need of oversampling. The fact that the current is smoothed due to motor inductance doesn't need all the precise timing, meanwhile in previous method it is crucial. Also keep in mind that during switching, the current is not flat, rather increasing/decreasing with L/R ratio, so doing a moving average filter could give a wrong current estimation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic adc, and clock it off the same source as the PWM generator. You will have synchronous sampling without a trigger and the same number of conversion results per PWM period.

Summing would have to be either external or some ADC allow a number of samples summed.